# Bootstrap 3 - Footer sitting to the right of the page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My footer is sitting to the right of the page for some reason. I cant figure out what is causing it.

[image]

Here is the html

```
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-social-accs pull-left">
        <nav>
          <h4>Boring Links</h4>

          <ul class="pull-left">
            <li>
              <%= link_to "About", about_path %>
            </li>
            <li>
              <%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %>
            </li>
            <li>
              <%= link_to "Terms", root_path %>
            </li>
            <li>
              <%= link_to "Privacy Policy", root_path %>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>

      <div class="navbar-social-accs pull-right">
        <nav>
          <h4>Follow Us!</h4>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <%= link_to "About", about_path %>
            </li>
            <li>
              <%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %>
            </li>
            <li>
              <%= link_to "Terms", root_path %>
            </li>
            <li>
              <%= link_to "Privacy Policy", root_path %>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

css

```
/* footer */

footer {
  margin-top: 45px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  color: $gray;
  a {
    color: $black-gray;
    &:hover {
      color: $black-gray;
    }
  }
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  ul{ padding:15px;
    li { list-style-type: none; }

    }
}
```

I would add padding if there was just white space to the left of it but it is actually being pushed to the right which makes the page wider than it should be and throws the footer of center.

Comment: Can you  make a codepen/jsfiddle? try adding `left: 0` to start with

Comment: `left: 0` worked. No idea what that does or why it worked. If you can post it as an answer I'll give it to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `left: 0;` to `.footer` to normalize layout

```
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0; /** Added **/
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  ul{ padding:15px;
    li { list-style-type: none; }

    }
}
```